# What is the correct way to access/use Grafana variable in the angular template of grafana?

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I want to use Grafana variable in the angular template.

I tried to access the variable by different methods such as:
1.**const host = '{{ host }}';**

2.**const host = '$host';**

3.**const host = angular.element(document.getElementById('host')).attr('ng-bind');**

4.**const host = angular.element(document.getElementById('host')).scope().$ctrl.variable.current.value;**

5. **const host = `${__host}`;**

None of the methods worked.
Any assistance or insights would be immensely helpful and valued.